# Can't get Go http to return an error; 'No data recieved'

Tags: postgresql, api, go

I am doing attempting to build a basic API using Go which returns the results of a SQL query using the [PostgreSQL library](https://github.com/lib/pq).

At the moment I can make the program return the values, but I can't get it to return a failed message to the user i.e. some JSON with an error message.

I have an error function as follows :

```
func handleError(w http.ResponseWriter, err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err.Error() + "\r\n") // Logging
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
}
```

However the http.Error method doesn't appear to ever return anything. The error thrown is a table that doesn't exist in the database (which gets logged to a text file: i.e. 2016/01/11 23:28:19 pq: relation "building_roof" does not exist

My programmes query code looks like this:

```
table := pq.QuoteIdentifier(table)
identifier := pq.QuoteIdentifier("ID")
rows, err := db.Query( fmt.Sprintf("SELECT %s, ST_AsText(geom) FROM %s WHERE %s = $1", identifier, table, identifier), feature)
handleError(w, err)
```

Causing an error just gives a Chrome error:

No data received

ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

EDIT Full Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "os"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "database/sql"
    "strings"
    "time"
    "github.com/lib/pq"
)


func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    f, err := os.OpenFile("pgdump_errorlog.txt", os.O_RDWR | os.O_CREATE | os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    log.Print("Couldn't open file")
    defer f.Close()
    log.SetOutput(f)

    // Timing
    start := time.Now()

    // Postgres Credentials
    const (
        DB_USER     = "postgres"
        DB_PASSWORD = "OMITTED" // Removed details !
        DB_PORT     = "OMITTED"
        DB_NAME     = "OMITTED"
    )

    // Postgres Connect
    dbinfo := fmt.Sprintf("user=%s password=%s dbname=%s port=%s sslmode=disable",
                           DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_PORT)
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", dbinfo)
    handleError(w, err)
    defer db.Close()

    table := r.FormValue("table")
    feature := r.FormValue("id")
    if table != "" {

        //Postgres Query
        var (
            id int
            geom string
        )

        table := pq.QuoteIdentifier(table)
        identifier := pq.QuoteIdentifier("ID")
        rows, qerr := db.Query( fmt.Sprintf("SELECT %s, ST_AsText(geom) FROM %s WHERE %s = $1", identifier, table, identifier), feature)
        handleError(w, err)
        defer rows.Close()
        for rows.Next() {
            err := rows.Scan(&id, &geom)
            handleError(w, err)
        }
        err = rows.Err()
        handleError(w, err)

        // Maniplate Strings
        returngeom := strings.Replace(geom, "1.#QNAN", "", -1)
        i := strings.Index(returngeom, "(")
        wkt := strings.TrimSpace(returngeom[:i])
        returngeom = returngeom[i:]

        type WTKJSON struct {
            WTKType   string
            Geometry  string
            Elapsed   time.Duration
        }

        returnjson := WTKJSON{Geometry:  returngeom, WTKType: wkt , Elapsed: time.Since(start)/1000000.0}
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(returnjson)

    }

}

func handleError(w http.ResponseWriter, err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err.Error() + "\r\n") // Logging
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
}


func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Comment: Can you show your main where you set up the routes ect?

Comment: I've left the full code for you to dissect if you so wish :)

Comment: Some debugging tips: Set log output once in main instead of setting it on every call to the handler.  Every call to handleError should be replaced by `if err != nil { handleError(err); return }`. Log the error returned from the call to the JSON encoder.

Comment: not familiar with go, if there is no response, that means response thread is crashed or hang. file handling in "func handler" is a call for a disaster if simultaneously 2 ruining requests appear. you should trap any errors in "handler" so that no errors will be raised directly and in case of failure, it cold respond to client with a response.

Answer (score 0):

The following appeared to allow me to return JSON Errors:

```
func handleError(w http.ResponseWriter, err string) {
    type APIError struct {
        Error string
    }
    re, _ := json.Marshal(APIError{Error: err})
    io.WriteString(w, string(re))
}
```

Used like so:

```
rows, err := db.Query( fmt.Sprintf("SELECT %s, ST_AsText(geom) FROM %s WHERE %s = $1", identifier, table, identifier), feature)
        if err != nil {
            handleError(w, err.Error())
            return
        }
```

Not suggesting this is the best method, but worked in my case.

Answer (score -1):

When you are using the http.Error function the error message should a string. For simple testing I would suggest take this line

```
http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
```

and change it to something like

```
http.Error(w,"there was an error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
```

and see if that response comes through. If it does its likely that you are trying to pass something that isn't a string in http.Error()

Comment: If `err` is an error interface then err.Error() must be a string by definition. It also wouldn't compile.